# Using totient functions - undefined issues

Tags: python, function

From [Python ProblemSet](http://wiki.python.org/moin/ProblemSets/99%20Prolog%20Problems%20Solutions) I would like to test the following functions but it seems that mult and coprime could not be defined. I tried importing math but that did not help. Any recommendations?

```
>>> import itertools
>>> def prime_factors(value):
    if value > 3:
        for this in itertools.chain(iter([2]), xrange(3,int(value ** 0.5)+1, 2)):
            if this*this > value:  break
            while not (value % this):
                if value == this: break
                value /=  this
                yield this
    yield value
>>> prime_factors(315)
generator object prime_factors at 0x01182468>
>>> def prime_factors_mult(n):
    res = list(prime_factors(n))
    return sorted([fact, res.count(fact)] for fact in set(res))
>>> prime_factors_mult(315)
[[3, 2], [5, 1], [7, 1]]
>>> def totient(n):
    from operator import mul
    if n == 1: return 1
    return reduce(mul, [(p-1) * p**(m-1) for p,m in prime_factors_mult(n)])

>>> totient(315)
144
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you check the documentation for the [operator module](http://docs.python.org/library/operator.html), you'll find that the multiplication operator is `mul`.

Also, I believe the definition of `coprime` relies on definitions from previous problems.

Comment: Thanks, that got everything working but I would like to determine the totient without having to query each function by hand every time. Is there an easy way to do this or should I ask a new question?

Comment: Disregard, going to just ask a new question.